# Script that waits for a variable to be loaded, alternative to setTimeout

Tags: jquery

The following script uses setTimeout() to wait for a variable to get a value (it's value is generated by another script which loads async):

```
function optinLoad(){

    if (!isEmpty(prefSource)){
        // do something

    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            optinLoad();
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to handle this besideds setTimeout()... Maybe a load function, which triggers the instance "prefSource" is not empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged this with jQuery, **use promises**, they're already available to you:

```
optinLoad().done(function (perfSource) {
  // Do Something

});

function optinLoad() {
  dfd = $.Deferred()

  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (!isEmpty(prefSource)) {
      clearInterval(interval)
      dfd.resolve(prefSource);
    } else {
      // Do whatever to load prefSource
    }
  }, 1000);


  return dfd.promise()
}
```

Comment: Ty for the answer, I need to wait for prefSource to load (its a variable) and that launch optinLoad function